# Out of memory exception in .net winform treeview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listview, treeview, out-of-memory

I have a treeview and based on items of treeview i have listview on right side. SO almost UI is our windows Explorer kind of appearance. So now the problem i am facing is when i delete large number of objects from listview coming right side, the treeview on the left side became partially painted(small portion i can say).When i attahced CLR excpetion from VS IDE ,it point to the line sampletree.EndUpdate(); with an exception out of memory. When i add a next item in listview everything come normal i mean treeview is fully painted
Exception i am getting is

```
System.OutOfMemoryException occurred
  Message=Out of memory.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal(IntPtr hdc)
       at System.Drawing.Font.ToLogFont(Object logFont)
       at System.Drawing.Font.ToHfont()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.FontHandleWrapper..ctor(Font font)
       at System.Windows.Forms.OwnerDrawPropertyBag.get_FontHandle()
       at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.CustomDraw(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WmNotify(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmNotify(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.EndUpdateInternal(Boolean invalidate)
       at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.EndUpdate()
```

Do you have any idea why i my treeview is painted only a samll part and successive modification paints fully? code snippet is shown belowe

```
 if( ( values != null ) &&
       ( values .OverallState != ToBeDeleted ) &&
       ( values .OverallState != .Deleted ) )
    {
       TreeView tree = this.TreeView;
       if( tree != null )
       {
          tree.BeginUpdate();
       }
       TryUpdate();
       TryPopulate();
       if( tree != null )
       {
          tree.EndUpdate();  // here exception coming
       }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I am using Font like this way

```
case State.Modified:
                     NodeFont = new Font(TreeView.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
break;
```

Does that make any issues

Comment: DO the winform treeview has any known issues, or any index is becoming -1?

Comment: Same issue here. The Task Manager shows that the process has 10,000 GDI font handles created (and then it crashes, 10,000 is the max). It happens only when I create a lot of nodes at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of crash is commonly caused by leaking GDI resources.  Which is very commonly caused by forgetting to call the Dispose() method on any System.Drawing class object.  Usually the garbage collector cleans up after you but, especially when you use ownerdraw, it might not run often enough to keep you out of trouble.  Windows pulls the plug on your program when you've consumed 10,000 GDI objects, the kaboom is the result.

You can easily diagnose this from Task Manager.  View + Select Columns and tick Handles, USER objects and GDI objects.  Observe those added columns for your process while you are using it.  A steadily climbing number predicts the OOM Kaboom.

Look in your DrawNode event handler first since it is likely to be called frequently.  But it can be caused by other painting code as well.  Ensure you create drawing objects like Graphics, Pen, Brush, Font, etc with the *using* statement so they are guaranteed to be disposed after usage.  The diagnostic you get from Task Manager tells you when you're ahead.

Comment: you may be correct, what i am wondering now is when issue comes(treeview cutting half) after deleting lot objects , again when you add a single object ,everything will become normal, what would be the reason??

Comment: There is little point in wondering over this, clearly less data causes less handles you could forget to dispose.  Use facts, what did Task Manager tell you?

Comment: Task manager showed Handles, USER objects and GDI objects an increase in counts, but not continous and it stopped somwhere and started decreasing to a some values.I modified my question. When using Font i didtn used using statement

Comment: It looks that the problem (the missing Dispose(), using{} blocks) is in the .NET internal drawing method itself. The problem appears changing the NodeFont, not customizing the node drawing code (GDI objects rise 10,000). Also the problem isn't because the creation of several Font() instances (you can create just one), but the problem is that we change NodeFont of several nodes. (The TreeView .NET drawing code is creating a LOGFONT or HFONT internally and isn't disposing the object immediately.)

Comment: I think it's a bug in the treeview as well. I have processexplorer up and it shows GDI count going up 4k every time I set a node text. Of course this doesn't last long. This is after fully loading the tree initially. Initially everything is fine. Try to edit a node text and bang, GDI count skyrockets. It seems to be related to the size of the tree. I'm going to try syncfusion's tree.

Comment: I also think it is a TreeView bug. I managed to work around it by reducing the number of nodes for which I execute `NodeFont = some font`. Now my code checks to see whether the Node has Bold font before setting the font, and I set the Node to not-bold by setting the NodeFont to `null`. The issue was not related to creating too many Font objects - I was only using two (and now only one since I realised I don't need a Font object for not-bold, just use `null`)

Answer (score 1):

I've just hit exactly the same problem. It only seems to occur in Windows systems later than XP, and, when I removed the `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` calls, it doesn't occur.

So, as a workaround, I'd say try removing the `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` calls. It does mean that there may be some visual stuttering while your nodes are being updated, but, on the plus side, it won't crash. That's surely a net win.

I've found nothing on MSDN/Connect which addresses this problem and I haven't the time right now to put together a self-contained test case, but I do think it's a bug in the handling of bulk updates in TreeViews in later versions of Windows.

Comment: Also, if you simply replace `BeginUpdate()` with `myTreeView.Visible = false` and the `EndUpdate()` with `myTreeView.Visible = true` - you avoid all screen flickering and still don't run into the bug. (Also this seems to have a pretty decent performance.)

Answer (score 1):

You can force the garbage collector with `System.GC.Collect()` after changing the nodefont or color.