# ImageList throws "Out of memory" exception when adding images from SQL database

Tags: c#, winforms, memorystream, imagelist

I have a few SQL databases which has a table that store images using `varbinary` datatype.

On button click, it will remove all existing images except the first three images from the `ImageList` control and add all new images to the `ImageList` on my form.

There is a `TreeView` that uses this `ImageList`.

I've been getting:

> Out of memory exception

...if I click the button **many times** on the **same** database.

Simplified code:

```
if(imageList1.Images.Count > 3)
{
    for (int i = imageList1.Images.Count - 1; i > 2; i--)
    {
       imageList1.Images.RemoveAt(i);      
    }
}
int counter = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (dr["ImageField"] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        byte[] imageData = (byte[])dr["ImageField"];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(ms);
        imageList1.Images.Add("Image" + counter, img);
        img.Dispose();
        ms.Dispose();
        counter++;
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal(IntPtr hdc)
   at System.Drawing.Font.ToLogFont(Object logFont)
   at System.Drawing.Font.ToHfont()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.FontHandleWrapper..ctor(Font font)
   at System.Windows.Forms.OwnerDrawPropertyBag.get_FontHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.CustomDraw(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WmNotify(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmNotify(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.EndUpdateInternal(Boolean invalidate)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.ImageListChangedHandle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.OnChangeHandle(EventArgs eventargs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.ImageCollection.Add(Original original, ImageInfo imageInfo)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.ImageCollection.Add(String key, Image image)
   at Test.MyClass.LoadLibraryImageList()
```

Why does it throw that exception when the memory usage is very low?

Comment: Prefer wrapping the usage of objects that implement `IDisposable` in `using` statements, rather than explicitly calling `Dispose`.

Comment: That first loop isnt disposing of any of those images.  If there are a lot and/or you do this repeatedly, you can run out of resources.  Additionally, this seems like the wrong use for the imagelist

Comment: @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain How should I dispose those unwanted images? I updated my question, I have a `TreeView` that uses this `ImageList`, each database has different images, how should I store the images for my `TreeView`?

Comment: It looks like that you are also using some Fonts (owner drawn TreeView?). You're probably out of handles and/or GDI objects at this point. If you create a disposable object, it's up to you to dispose of it.

Comment: @Jimi I do have a `MultiSelectTreeView` that extends `TreeView` class

Comment: `imageList1.Images.Add("Image" + counter, img);
        img.Dispose();` I am not sure it is a good idea to add an image somewhere, then `Dispose` it straight away.

Comment: `imageList1.Images.RemoveAt(i);` I suspect this is where you should **really** be `Dispose` the images - just before you remove them.

Comment: Yes, I figured something like that. The ImageList may not be the only problem. It might not even be the real one. However, see [this note in the Reference code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ImageList.cs,71) about the ImageList and the internal handles. This is actually a problem sometimes. You should probably dispose of the ImageList altogether (ImageList overrides Dispose() and disposes of all the Images it creates), then add back the images you want to keep. What other handles you're using there is unknown.

Comment: See the [overriden Dispose()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ImageList.cs,587) internal method.

Comment: @Jimi I monitored the task manager - GDI objects and notice that occasionally it went up to 10,000 when I dispose the images from `ImageList`

Comment: 10.000 handles is the death of it. The system will say goodby to your app. It's actually difficult (in managed code) to go that far. You are probably leaking handles all over the place. Start with disposing of the Image (at that same Index) before calling `RemoveAt()`, which will simply resize-copy the underlying ArrayList. But I'ld monitor the app **without** that ImageList, to see whether you have a problem elsewhere, the ImageList being the last drop.

Comment: My previous suggestion - dispose of the ImageList and add back the few images you want to keep - stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `ImageList` is just the tip of the iceberg, the real problem lays in my extended `MultiSelectTreeView` control. After reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147635/out-of-memory-exception-in-net-winform-treeview), I added `GC.Collect()` to my code whenever I change the `TreeNode` font and voila, problem solved.

From the suggestions, I also dispose unwanted images from my `ImageList` before loading a new batch which seems to help lower my GDI counts too. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You must dispose images when you remove them (see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181693/removeatx-does-it-dispose-the-element-x) for an explanation).

Also, a while loop is simpler. Just remove the last image in the list until only 3 remain.

```
void RemoveLastImage(ImageList imageList)
{
    var lastIndex = imageList.Images.Count - 1;
    var lastImage = imageList.Images[lastIndex];
    imageList.Images.RemoveAt(lastIndex);
    lastImage.Dispose();
}

while (imageList1.Images.Count > 3)
{
    RemoveLastImage(imageList1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `while` loop suggestion, it's cleaner. However, this doesn't solve my problem. I think the real problem might be somewhere else.